# when to use makemigrations in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am following tutorials on Django [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/). The Docs have mentioned:

> By running makemigrations, you’re telling Django that you’ve made some
>   changes to your models (in this case, you’ve made new ones) and that
>   you’d like the changes to be stored as a migration

I don't understand this line. Here in tutorial they ran `makemigrations` only when they created two **classes** i.e. **Question** & **Choice** in `polls/models.py`. However, they didn't ran `makemigrations` when they modified(or I would say re-implemented) `__str__()` method in **sub classes**: **Question** & **Choice**. Also, they added a custom method(or action) i.e. `was_published_recently()` in **Choice** **subclass**.

I guess they should have run makemigrations after adding those methods as well?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
import datetime

# Create your models here.

@python_2_unicode_compatible   # Only if you need to support Python 2
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('published date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


@python_2_unicode_compatible   # Only if you need to support Python 2
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Migrations are only necessary when the database will be altered (e.g. deleting / adding a model, modifying fields, etc.). Adding methods doesn't affect the database.

Comment: so in short I need to run them mostly when I add classes, remove classes? @rnevius

Comment: Or when you add fields, remove fields, rename fields, alter fields, rename classes, etc. Yep!

Comment: Note that there are changes that require a new migration, that will not change the database schema, for example changing a fields `verbose_name` or `help_text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrations describe changes that must be made to the definitions in the underlying database, but not everything in a Django model corresponds directly to the database. Overwriting the `__str__` method and adding the `was_published_recently` method don't require any database changes.

Adding a new class isn't the only time you might need to run migrations: if you wanted questions to be written in different colors, you might add this to the `Question` model:

```
color = models.CharField(max_length=6)  # font color hex code
```

This change entails a change to the database schema, so it would require a migration.